# vba compare row to column

Tags: vba, excel, comparison

I have a spreadsheet where column A information starts on row 6 and I have the unique values from this list as headers across the top in Row 1 starting at column D. What I want to do is if a cell in column A matches a header row, copy the information in the cell in column C to the corresponding Header.

**ORIGINAL FORMAT**
[image]

**DESIRED FORMAT**
[image]

Here is the code that I have tried but it is not giving me the desired results:

```
For i = 6 To lastRow
    For j = 4 To lastColumn
      If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(1, j) Then
        wksActRawData.Cells(i, 3).Value = wksActRawData.Cells(i, j).Value
      End If
    Next j
  Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you did write lastRow and lastColumn functions, the only error in your code is the data which gets the cell values

```
 If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(1, j) Then
    wksActRawData.Cells(i, 3).Value = wksActRawData.Cells(i, j).Value
 End If
```

Which should really be the other way around, plus I'd add a line to clear the old prices, as follows

```
  If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(1, j) Then
    Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value
    Cells(i, 3).ClearContents
  End If
```

It did work for me this way

Comment: Thanks, works great! Guess I've been staring at code way to long. I do have my lastRow and lastColumn functions. I am going to add in a line that just deletes the entire column.

Comment: Happens to me all the time. I guess deleting the column might work quicker with more data. Glad to be able to help.